# Changing the scale of the x axis in a plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Let's say I have a 2D array I plot using imshow. I want to be able to scale the x axis to the percent of the x axis. So I plot the data like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.random((10,10))

plt.show(plt.imshow(A,origin='low', extent=[0,10,0,10]))
```

Now I'm not sure how I can do that. Any insight?

EDIT: fixed to include extent as @tcaswell pointed out

Comment: That is not the right way to use `plt.show`.....  You want the `extent` kwarg.

Comment: That is still not how to use `show`.  Do you have a link to where says to do that like that?

Comment: scaling the x axis to the percent of x axis means x should go from 0..100 instead of 0..10? If so, then you just have to change the extent argument to `extent=[0,100,0,10]`. You could also add something like `plt.xlabel('x in %')` before using `plt.show()` to have a label. The `extend` keyword has the following parameters: `[x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max]`.